# Speaking Problems

Tags: speech

Being from Argentina, my native language is Spanish, but I love English. I started learning when I was six years old and I can't stop finding it wonderful. I always read long books in English and watch TV shows and videos. I even say English words when talking in Spanish because I almost practically think in English.

The thing is that I always get stuck while speaking. When I have to say something to somebody I have to think and rethink the sentence for like a minute before it gets off my mouth. Although, when I speak being alone (both inside my head or loudly) I can formulate complex sentences without making a single grammar error or trying to remember a word for some seconds.

Please, could somebody tell me how I can improve my speaking!!!

PS: Let me know if EL&U is the right community for this question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Unfortunately, *generic questions on improving one's English* is explicitly [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site. Have a look at the other [help] articles; then if you have a specific question about the English language, feel free to ask. Consider participating in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) at [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: listen to BBC transmissions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on improving one's English are explicitly listed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many have the same problems as you do when they learn English few hours a week.
I think the way to improve speaking fluently by teaching English . Volunteering your times to teach, first try elementary level with a dozen of Kids, you got to speak a lot and loud .